# Is it possible to send logs to Logstash

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback

In my Spring Boot app, I am using Logback to write logs to a file in /tmp/myLog.log.

In my app.yml:

```
logging:
  file: /tmp/myLog.log
```

My logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } [%t] --- %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n"/>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Then I tell Logstash to look at this log file, in my conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/myLog.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

Now It is looking at this location at myLog.log. Is there a way to send logs to logstash instead of telling it to looking at a location, in my Spring Boot app?

Comment: logstash has other inputs, including tcp{} and udp{}.  If your logging system can send the data to a port, logstash can listen for them without using an intermediate file.  However, be sure to figure out what happens to your logs if logstash is down (or elasticsearch is congested, etc).

Answer (score 3):

I was successfully playing around with the [Logback-Elasticsearch-Appender](https://github.com/internetitem/logback-elasticsearch-appender). You might want to give it a try.